# How do all chemical reactions result in a product whose potential is less than the reactants if all reactions are not exothermic?

Tags: thermodynamics

We are told by our chemistry teacher that all chemical reactions take place as reactants (that have bigger potential) change into products (that have smaller potential) hence unstable substances change into more stable ones. But doesn't this mean "all reactions are exothermic"? I am in need of a clarification, please.

Comment: 'Spontaneous' reactions show a negative change in Gibbs Free Energy ($\Delta G <0$).

Comment: Some reactions are endothermic, and require energy input to proceed.  Many (or most) of these endothermic reactions produce products that are more energetic than the reactants.  The reactions to produce TNT or nitroglycerine come to mind.

Comment: Perhaps you could wait for developments at the course? Else see comment above.

Answer (score 0):

"Potential," as your teacher is using it, is not exactly the same as energy. (S)he is likely talking about the Gibbs energy $G$, which is a combination property

$$G = H - TS$$

where $H$ is the enthalpy. If we think about the change in $G$:

$$ \Delta G = \Delta H - \Delta (T S) $$

One way of reducing $G$ is to reduce $H$ (which chemists usually think of as "exothermic"), but it is also possible to increase $H$ (which chemists usually think of as "endothermic") provided that you simultaneously increase the product $T S$ by more.

When labelling a reaction as endothermic/exothermic, chemists usually think about $\Delta H$, but when labelling a substance as stable or unstable, they usually think $G$.